# html <img> tag is not displaying the image using php in the browser

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

html  tag is not displaying the image and I am trying to display html file through php file.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img name="Userphoto" alt="Userphoto" src="img/50X50.png"> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<form name="Dashboard">
    <div class="frame1">
        <?php include 'frame1.html'; ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can load view inside view or controller with codeigniter.

Comment: frame1.html work perfectly ??? try just run frame1.html single without using php include in another page

Comment: What happens instead? Have you tried checking whether the markup is valid?

Comment: Why are you including a file that starts with `<!DOCTYPE>` inside a `<div>`? The HTML you generate will be wildly invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTML file is called into PHP file so path is consider of PHP one

Better way is to convert your `html` file into `php` and define your `img` path as

```
  <img name="Userphoto" alt="Userphoto" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/50x50.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path to the image is not good since you included it in another file.

Let's say from your HTML file the path is "img/50X50.png", but if your php file is not in the same folder as your HTML code, the path isn't good.

Use absolute path and no more problems.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the image path is incorrect:
`src="img/50X50.png`
You can open Chrome Console to see the error message, which would indicate this, or provide another clue as to why the image hasn’t displayed.